# c# constructor vs initialize

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

Doing TDD and want to isolate the method under test: `Direct();`
However, when the test creates `MyClass`, `SomeClass.SetupStuff();` blows up (`NotImplementedException`).  So, modified the `IMyClass` interface to have a `Configure();` method that can be called after `MyClass` construction to avoid the exception.

Question: Is this an accepted way of handling this scenario or is there some basic OOP principal that this breaks?

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
  public MyClass()
  {
     // class with static method that sets stuff up
     SomeClass.SetupStuff();
  }
  public void IMyClass.Direct()
  {
     // want to test this
  }
}
```

vs

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
  public MyClass()
  {

  }
  public void IMyClass.Direct()
  {
     // want to test this
  }
  //
  public void IMyClass.Configure()
  {
    // class with static method that sets stuff up
    SomeClass.SetupStuff();
  }
}
```

Comment: Setting up static data in instance method seems odd to me.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. If you're doing TDD then that means your tests *should fail* until you implement what needs implemented. If you haven't implemented `SomeClass.SetupStuff` then you'll need to implement it to get the test to pass. I guess I just don't understand the problem here. Move the code back to the `.ctor` and implement the method. Boom, test passes.

Comment: Why not inject SomeClass via the constructor. Don't make it static. And than just mock it for your test. Your class seems dependent on SomeClass right now. You want to test Direct() not SomeClass

Comment: Additionally, I'd mention that the static setup is rather bad practice, because it hides an important dependency. Static classes should generally be stateless, and when something like this is required, a singleton that implements an interface is a better idea, because you can pass in the singleton through an interface, ensuring that your code in this object doesn't care whether any part of it's dependencies are static or not.

Comment: @neoistheone - Yes I agree. However, unit testing is about testing the smallest unit possible, in this case I do not want to test SomeClass at all.  When I start writing tests for SomeClass.SetupStuff, then I will get it to pass.

Comment: @Sean - The method is static for a reason, the class is not.  The reason it is static is because the method need only be called once to properly setup an external dependency (in this case AutoMapper which itself is a singleton).  It would not make sense to call this method twice, ever.  So, I don't see why I would make it non-static.

Answer (score 5):

One way to avoid such problems is to use dependency injection

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public MyClass(ISomeClass someClass)
    {
        someClass.SetupStuff();
    }

    public void IMyClass.Direct()
    {
       // want to test this
    }
}
```

By decoupling your class from SomeClass, you are free to provide a mock implementation of ISomeClass during test and can provide a full implementation at runtime.